# Pass function value to stored procedure in SSRS

Tags: function, datetime, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2012

I have a function that calculate time difference excluding weekends,  and I have created a stored procedure to call the function. When I tested the sp, only showed message part, I am new and not sure if this is correct. And I have trouble to pass the parameters to SSRS. Please help, many thanks.

```
Alter Proc Test_1 
@DownTime datetime,
@Uptime   datetime =null  --since there are some null value in uptime column
AS  
Begin

print 'enter'

declare @duration int 
select  @duration = [dbo].[CalcWorkMinutes](@DownTime,@Uptime)
print 'abc'

;with cte_test2
as (
SELECT DownTime
,UpTime
,datediff(hh,DownTime,UpTime)  AS duration
FROM Test
)

select DownTime,UpTime,duration from cte_test2

where  DownTime = @DownTime and UpTime=@UpTime 
and duration=@duration
--print 'pass'

print 'duration'+' '+convert(varchar,@duration)
RETURN 

END 
 --execute [dbo].[test_1] @downtime ='2017-06-02 09:00:00.000', @Uptime ='2017-06-05 09:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Asking question format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: Sorry, first time.

Comment: Hmm... There's a lot going on in this one.  It looks like you are trying to see what downtime was like across a certain timeframe someone will pass in?  If that is the case, I'd change the parameters to be: StartDate and EndDate.  You don't really need a CTE to apply the parameters... Code below... I am just taking a guess here though:  Opps have to put this in an answer

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... There's a lot going on in this one.  It looks like you are trying to see what downtime was like across a certain timeframe someone will pass in?  If that is the case, I'd change the parameters to be: StartDate and EndDate.  You don't really need a CTE to apply the parameters... Code below... I am just taking a guess here though:

```
    Alter Proc Test_1 
@startdate datetime,
@enddate   datetime   --since there are some null value in uptime column
AS  
Begin

print 'enter'



SELECT 
    DownTime
    ,UpTime
    ,[dbo].[CalcWorkMinutes](DownTime,UpTime)  AS duration
FROM Test as a
where 
    downtime >= @startdate
    and b.downtime < dateadd(day,1,@enddate) 


RETURN 

END
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I was stuck with the function variables. I have edit the SP like yours, the where clause. I don't need 4 variables, but only 2.

Comment: Great, yes, I forgot to take out the other two variables.